# A second order non-linear difference equations 

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to explicitly solve [ if possible and if the solution exists ]  a second order non-linear difference equation of the form :

$  a _ {n+2}  ^2  + a_{n} ^2 + K = \lambda a_{n+1} $, where K and $\lambda$ are known positive constants ( assume K =10 and $\lambda =5 $  if you like ).

Is there any reference for it ? Or any paper that talks about the solution ?

Comment: For existence, have you tried numerical experimentation?

Comment: No, actually I am not aware of how to do that, but could you suggest a reference or so ? I study pure Mathematics, so I don't know much about
numerical solutions etc . The difference equation arose part of my research.